# Interpreting select @@version

Tags: sql-server

Here is my output from 'select @@version'

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4583460) - 13.0.5108.50 (X64)   May 20 2022 20:28:29 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

In looking up this info at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/releases/download-and-install-latest-updates

I see KB4583460 corresponds to build number 13.0.5103.6 but my build number is 13.0.5108.50 which corresponds to KB5014365. Usually I see that the KB matches the build number from this statement. KB5014365 is a later update so I was expecting to just see the build number from this KB. Can someone explain how to interpret this output?

Comment: Do you see the same in your error log (during the last restart)?